# Pendulum equivalent to Arrow's replace() method?

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I have one UTC datetime string and one bare time string which I would like to compare.

```
pointTimeString = '2017-09-08T14:55:38Z'
startTimeString = '15:52'
```

The time is on the same date, but in British Summer Time, not UTC.

This works, but feels kind of hacky:

```
import pendulum

pointTime = pendulum.parse(pointTimeString)
startTime = pendulum.parse(pointTimeString[0:11]+startTimeString, tz='Europe/London')

if pointTime > startTime:
    # Do stuff
```

Pendulum uses the date to infer that the time in question is in BST and sets the UTC offset to +1:00. The pendulum [*raison d'être* post](http://blog.eustace.io/please-stop-using-arrow.html) explicitly calls out Arrow's `replace()` method as problematic, but I don't see an equivalent. Is the point that it's not possible to have a `replace()` equivalent which behaves correctly? Even if this is the case, is there not some way to copy a pendulum instance while setting the hour and the minute to something else?

I'm hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
import pendulum

pointTime = pendulum.parse(pointTimeString)
startTime = pointTime.in_tz('Europe/London').from_format(startTimeString, "%H:%m")

if pointTime > startTime:
    # Do stuff
```

Of course, this doesn't work at the moment: `AttributeError: 'Pendulum' object has no attribute 'from_format'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite as neat as I was looking for, but this is pretty expressive and definitely feels less hacky:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pendulum

pointDT = pendulum.parse(pointTimeString)
startTime = dt.strptime(startTimeString, "%H:%M").time()
startDT = pendulum.instance(dt.combine(pointDT.date(), startTime), tz="Europe/London")

if pointDT > startDT:
    # Do stuff
```

Inspired by the answer to [an issue](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues/156) on the project's Github site.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative.

```
>>> import pendulum

>>> pointTimeString = '2017-09-08T14:55:38Z'
>>> pointTime = pendulum.parse(pointTimeString)
>>> startTimeString = '15:52'
```

Create an instance of `pendulum` for just the date from `startTimeString`.

```
>>> tempTime = pendulum.parse(startTimeString)
```

Assemble the complete date from elements of `pointTimeString` and `tempTime`.

```
>>> startTime = pendulum.create(pointTime.year, pointTime.month, pointTime.day, tempTime.hour, tempTime.minute, 0, 0, tz=pointTime.tz)
```

Verify result.

```
>>> startTime
<Pendulum [2017-09-08T15:52:00+00:00]>
```

Verify, in particular, that timezones have been handled correctly.

```
>>> pointTime.tz
<Timezone [+00:00]>
>>> startTime.tz
<Timezone [+00:00]>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. [This trick](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues/82#issuecomment-267826106) might shorten the creation. The time zones are actually different in the question (UTC vs BST), but that's easy enough to change with your method as well. TBH, the more I look at my original solution, the more I feel like it might be the cleanest of the lot!